# A Tour of Go Exercise: rot13Reader, why is the reader called twice?

Tags: go

```
import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func (rot13 rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (int, error){
    n,err := rot13.r.Read(b)
    fmt.Printf("\n%v %v\n",n, err)
    const A byte ='A'
    const a byte ='a'
    for i,x := range b{
        if x==0 {
            n=i
            break
        }
        switch {
        case A<=x && x<a:
            tmp := x-A
            b[i] = A+((tmp+13)%26)
        case a<=x && x<a+26 :
            tmp := x-a
            b[i] = a+((tmp+13)%26)
        }
    }
    return n, err
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

The code above outputs

```
 
21 <nil>
You cracked the code!
0 EOF
Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!
```

I have two questions :

1. Why is the reader being called twice (the second call returning 0 and EOF)
2. Why does on the second call, `b` is back to the original chiper? If it reads 0 character, shouldn't it still be "You cracked the code!"?

Comment: 1) because `io.Copy` calls `Read` until EOF is returned, but your code calls `fmt.Printf` before returning EOF to `io.Copy`. You should check `err` returned by `rot13.r.Read(b)` before moving on with the program flow; 2) because by not returning, you're applying the cipher again on the same buffer, and then the `n` you return is non zero. https://go.dev/play/p/iAWmvuOMnzk

Comment: Thanks! I forgot that doing rot13 is its own inverse!